# Add/remove style after click label/input[radio] problem

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with a function that selects active items. There are some input/label fields with sectoins ( one section - one active/clicked element )
It only works when I double-click. If I click one time then no result. I can set setTimeout for that code and then works but not always.

Example:

```
var radios = document.querySelectorAll('#calculator input[type=radio]'); 
var label = document.querySelectorAll("#calculator label"); 

function active(e) {

    radios.forEach((el,index) => {
        if(el.checked === true) {
            console.log('true');
            label[index].classList.add('active');
        } else {
            console.log('false');
            label[index].classList.remove('active');
        }
    })

}
```

Example html field:

```
<input id="p75" type="radio" name="geodesic_size" value="11250" >
<label for="p75">
<input id="p30" type="radio" name="geodesic_size" value="5626" checked>
<label for="p30">
```

Comment: and when you call `active` function.

Comment: Let us see the rest of your code. Are you calling the function?

Comment: Thanks ... ok I see that event 'change' works with  <input>, <select>, and <textarea>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you need, but here's an example of toggling the `active` class when the checked input changes:

```js
const radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');
const label = document.querySelectorAll("label"); 

function active(e) {
  radios.forEach((el,index) => {
    if(el.checked === true) {
      console.log('true');
      label[index].classList.add('active');
    } else {
      console.log('false');
      label[index].classList.remove('active');
    }
  })
}

radios.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('change', active);
})
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input id="p75" type="radio" name="geodesic_size" value="11250" >
<label for="p75">First</label>
<input id="p30" type="radio" name="geodesic_size" value="5626" checked>
<label for="p30" class="active">Second</label>
```

Comment: Thank you :) it works but now I have two events: click and change pointing to a function 'active'. Maybe there are more optimal solutions ?

Comment: @Macsurf You should only need the `change` event calling `active`.

Comment: There is only one problem, when there is default checked field then if you click on it then no result because event 'change' will not be triggered. So I add async function toogle() to change elements and now is works good. Code has been attached to my last post. I am sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers seem to work fine, I would just add a couple suggestions:

First, you can also access the label(s) associated to an element with [HTMLInputElement.labels](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/labels). Using `el.labels[0]` would IMO be a bit more robust than relying on the index of the radio button and the label to be the same.

If all you need to do is toggle an `active` class like this, you could accomplish the same thing with CSS only by using the [adjacent sibling combinator (+)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) and get rid of all the JavaScript:

```css
input:checked + label {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="p75" type="radio" name="geodesic_size" value="11250">
  <label for="p75">p75</label>
</div>
<div>
  <input id="p30" type="radio" name="geodesic_size" value="5626" checked>
  <label for="p30">p30</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. You are absolutely right el.labels[0] is much better I will use it.

Answer (score 0):

- There was no major change I have just add `<div id="calculator"></div>`.

> As `#calculator input[type=radio]` this means select all input with type equals to radio, which are children of id `#calculator`.

- Then selected all inputs loop through them attach `onclick` event and put you logic for `active()` function there.
- To see visual effect added `.active{background-color:red;}` css.

```js
var radios = document.querySelectorAll('#calculator input[type=radio]');
var label = document.querySelectorAll("#calculator label");
radios.forEach(radioBtn => {
  radioBtn.onclick = function() {
    radios.forEach((el, index) => {
      console.log(el.checked);
      if (el.checked === true) {
        console.log('true');
        label[index].classList.add('active');
      } else {
        console.log('false');
        label[index].classList.remove('active');
      }
    })
  };
})
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="calculator">
  <input id="p75" type="radio" name="geodesic_size" value="11250">
  <label for="p75">p75</label>
  <input id="p30" type="radio" name="geodesic_size" value="5626" checked>
  <label for="p30">p30</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I noticed one problem with event 'change' for input fields. When I click on default element ( input default checked )  then there is no change but it is normal because the state has not changed and the event did not call the function active(). Of course we can add window.onload with that function to change the styles of the clicked element. But I modified the script to add an async function toogle() for checked elements and works very well.

```
function active() {
    radios.forEach(el => {
        if(el.checked === true) {
            toogle(el);
        } else {
        el.labels[0].classList.remove('active');
        el.labels[0].setAttribute('data-before', '');
        }
    });
}

async function toogle(el) {
    var f = await new Promise(resolve => {
        el.labels[0].classList.add('active');
        el.labels[0].setAttribute('data-before', '\uf058');
        resolve('resolved');
    })
    console.log(f);
}
```